# Using -ms-filter for transform IE8 fallback, Good practice or not?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I feature detect support for CSS transforms and use appropriate vendor prefixes if needed. Down to IE9 everything is fine but I also have to support IE8.

I can use -ms-filter:Matrix to fallback to something similar in IE8. Is this a good practice or not?

Looking forward to hearing pro and con arguments.

Comment: If it works, and you must have that feature in IE 8, and your fix doesn't interfere with other browsers ... Go for it!

Comment: Yeah agreed.  My CSS is often filled with ugly hacks just to keep support for older browsers.  You do what you have to do.

Comment: Was thinking the same. However I think it does not support translate.